# Measures: Atom Definitions

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, definition

Let $\Omega$ be a measure space with measure $\mu$.
*(Here, a measure is only meant to be countable additive!)*

Consider a subset $A\in\Sigma$.

Then according to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)) it is an atom if:
$$(1)\quad\forall E\subseteq A:\quad\mu(E)<\mu(A)\implies\mu(E)=0\quad(\mu(A)>0)$$
and according to the [paper by Johnson](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-03/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8.pdf) it is an atom if:
$$(2)\quad\forall E\in\Sigma:\quad\mu(E\cap A)=0\lor\mu(E^c\cap A)=0\quad(\mu(A)>0)$$

Now, these definitions agree for the really trivial cases:
$$\mu\equiv0$$
$$\mu\equiv\infty$$
but they differ for the less trivial case:
$$\quad\mu(E\neq\varnothing):=\infty,\,\mu(\varnothing):=0$$
namely the atoms are w.r.t. (1) all nonempty subsets whereas w.r.t. (2) only the singletons.

Excluding this pathological case, are the definitions equivalent?
*(More precisely, assume there exists a measurable subset $0<\mu(F)<\infty$.)*

So far I checked that:
$$(2)\implies(1):\quad\mu(E)<\mu(A)\implies\mu(A\setminus E)>0\implies\mu(E)=0$$
but what about the other direction?

Comment: The second definition *definitely* has a typo.

Comment: Yepp, a complement was missing, thanks, corrected!

Comment: The pathological case you want to exclude is $\mu(A)=\infty$. Just the fact that there is a set of finite measure *somewhere* tells you nothing at all about $A$.

Comment: @tomasz: Riiight one could just adjoin a finite measure space to the pathological one $\Omega_{pathological}\sqcup\Omega_{finite}$ getting again the same problem...

Comment: @tomasz: But what about the sigma-finite case then as studied in the paper?

Comment: @Freeze_S: If the measure is $\sigma$-finite, there can be no atoms of infinite measure, as any set can be partitioned into (countably many) sets of finite measure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*First, as mentioned in the comments excluding the pathological case is not enough:*
(Thanks alot @tomasz!!)

Consider the measure space:
$$\mu:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\cup{\infty})\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_+:\quad\mu(\varnothing):=0,\;\mu(\{\infty\}):=1,\;\mu(E):=\infty\text{ else}$$
Then the atoms are w.r.t. (1) all nonempty subsets whereas w.r.t. (2) only the singletons
and for both (1) and (2) additionally the point at infinity.

---

*Next, for atoms of finite mass the proof goes as follows:*
(Thanks alot @asaf karagila!!)

Assume, it holds (1). Let $E\in\Sigma$ arbitrary.

If $\mu(A\cap E)=0$ we're done.
Otherwise $\mu(A\cap E)=\mu(A)$ by (1). But then $\mu(A\cap E^c)=0$ as $\mu(A)<\infty$ and we're done, too.

Concluding that (2) holds.

---

*Finally, for the sigma-finite case atoms have finite mass and the preceding applies:*

Assume $A$ is an atom w.r.t. (1) with $\mu(A)=\infty$.

By sigma-finiteness, there exists a sequence $A_n\uparrow A$ with $\mu(A_n)<\infty$.
By continuity, there exists a natural $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\mu(A_{n_0})>0$.
By defintion of an atom, this implies $\mu(A_n)=\mu(A)=\infty$.
Contradiction!

Concluding that $\mu(A)<\infty$.