# Borel Measures: Atoms vs. Point Masses

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, definition

Let a measure be $\mu:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}_+$.

Call a measurable $A\subset\Sigma$ an atom if:
$$\mu(A)>0:\quad\mu(E)<\mu(A)\implies\mu(E)=0\quad(E\subseteq A)$$
and a singleton $\{a\}\in\Sigma$ a point mass if:
$$\mu(\{a\})>0$$

First of all, for singletons the notion of atoms and point masses coincide.

Next, for sigma-finite spaces the defintion of an atom is equivalent to:
$$\mu(A)>0:\quad\mu(A\cap E)=0\lor\mu(A\cap E^c)=0$$
*(For more details see: [Measure Atoms: Definition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/974065/79762))*

That is every atom splits into smaller atoms, so one could try to apply Zorn's lemma here.

Now, given a sigma-finite Borel measure $\lambda:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}_+$.

Does every atom arise from a point mass?

Comment: Aren't you missing something akin to $E\subset A$, $E$ being a proper subset?

Comment: Yepp, added it...

Comment: By the way, your Zorn argument doesn't work.  The natural thing to do is to partially order the atoms in $\Sigma$ by reverse inclusion.  Given a chain $\{E_i\}_{i \in I}$ of atoms, to invoke Zorn you need to show it has an upper bound, i.e. an atom $E$ with $E \subset E_i$ for all $i$.  The obvious candidate is $E := \bigcap_i E_i$, but if the chain is uncountable then this is an uncountable intersection, and you can't be sure that its measure is the same as that of the $E_i$s, or even that it is measurable at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yepp, thats a problem. But that would suggest to pick that point to construct a counterexample for a Borel algebra having atoms but no point masses, right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you give actually is a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure.  Equip $[0,1]$ with the cofinite topology (in which a set is open iff it is either empty or its complement is finite).  Then your $\Sigma$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the cofinite topology (it is a nice exercise to verify this).

However, there is the following result:

**Proposition**.  Let $(X,d)$ be a separable metric space, $\Sigma$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu$ a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\Sigma$.  Then each atom of $\mu$ is the union of a point mass and a null set.

*Proof.*  Let $C$ be a countable dense subset of $X$.  For each integer $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $\bigcup_{x \in C} B(x, 1/k) = X$.  Thus $\bigcup_{x \in C} (A \cap B(x,1/k)) = A$.  So by countable additivity, there exists $x_k \in C$ such that $\mu(A \cap B(x_k, 1/k)) > 0$.  Since $A$ is an atom, $\mu(A \setminus B(x_k, 1/k)) = 0$.  Let $S = \bigcap_k B(x_k, 1/k)$.
Since for each $k$, $S$ is contained in a ball of radius $1/k$, $S$ contains at most one point.
On the other hand, by De Morgan's law and countable additivity,
$$\mu(A \setminus S) = \mu\left(\bigcup_k A \setminus B(x_k, 1/k)\right) = 0.$$
Since $\mu(A\cap S)=\mu(A) > 0$, $A\cap S$ is not empty, so $A\cap S$ is a singleton.
Hence $A\cap S$ is a point mass and $A \setminus S$ a null set.  $\Box$

So in this case, effectively the only atoms are point masses.

Note that we did not need to assume $X$ was complete.

For non-separable metric spaces, things are harder.  For uncountable discrete spaces (which are certainly metric), the question of whether there can be nontrivial  atoms is related to whether the cardinality of $X$ is a [measurable cardinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal), and such questions tend to be independent of the axioms of ZFC.  I asked a new question about it: [Consistency strength of 0-1 valued Borel measures](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988711/consistency-strength-of-0-1-valued-borel-measures).

Comment: So for non-separable metric spaces the question is not certainly answerable?

Comment: Don't you also need completeness besides searability?

Comment: In the proof I sketched in my head, I don't think I needed completeness, but I will have to check.  Regarding non-separable spaces, I'm not completely sure.  If there exists a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ then $\kappa$ with the discrete topology, equipped with a measure that assigns measure 1 to any set of cardinality $\kappa$ and measure 0 to everything else, is an atom that is not a point mass.  But there may conceivably be another way to construct such a thing in ZFC.  I just do not know.

Comment: @Freeze_S: I added a proof of my proposition; we do not need completeness.

Comment: Great! So everything works out fine =)

Comment: I linked your answer on a summary thread with mentioning you. Is this ok for you? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/989196/borel-measures-atoms-summary

Answer (score 1):

**No, in general this is wrong!**

Consider the Borel algebra generated by the cofinite topology:
$$\Sigma:=\{E\subseteq[0,1]:\#E\leq\aleph_0\lor\#E^c\leq\aleph_0\}=\sigma(\mathcal{T}_{cofinite})$$
*(See the thread on: [Cofinite Topology: Borel Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/987892/79762))*
and the finite Borel measure:
$$\lambda(\#E\leq\aleph_0):=0$$
$$\lambda(\#E^c\leq\aleph_0):=1$$
Then the atoms are all the uncountables but no singleton is a point mass.