# Cofinite Topology: Borel Algebra

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Given the cofinite topology:
$$\mathcal{T}:=\{U\subseteq\Omega:\#U^c<\infty\}$$
and generate its Borel algebra:
$$\sigma(\mathcal{T})=\{E\subseteq\Omega:\#E\leq\aleph_0\lor\#E^c\leq\aleph_0\}$$
Why is this its Borel algebra?

Intuitively, this makes sense but rigorously?

Comment: Have you tried using the definition?

Comment: Ah you mean like check that this is a sigma algebra and check that any sigma algebra containing the topology must contain that sigma algebra concluding it is the one genereated by the topology, right?

Comment: Yeess, Exactly!

Comment: Can you put it as answer, please? *(So I can check it off.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Without proof:*

It is a sigma algebra.

It contains the cofinite topology.

Any sigma algebra containing the cofinite topology must in fact contain it.

Thus, it is its Borel algebra by definition.